# Why SUMO output different using veins_launchd and without veins_launchd?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

First, I use veins_launchd to conect omnet and sumo, the command line is "D:/example_project/veins-5.1/veins-veins-5.1/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse/bin/sumo.exe' "
The ouput lane data is shown below:
[image]

But I want to run SUMO manually, so I modify *TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd* to *TraCIScenarioManager* and use the command line "sumo -c llcd.sumocfg --remote-port 9999", and then waiting for omnet to connected. This approach is inspired by this answer [Is there a way to connect multiple TraCI modules to the OMNet++/veins simulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830844/is-there-a-way-to-connect-multiple-traci-modules-to-the-omnet-veins-simulation)

But when I run this way, the output result is like this:
[image]

Why do simulation results make such a huge difference? I didn't change any other parameters, and the sumo configure file is the same.

some of the parameter setting in omnetpp.ini:

```
##########################################################
#            TraCIScenarioManager parameters             #
##########################################################
*.manager.updateInterval = 1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = false
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("llcd.launchd.xml")
```

sumo.config:

```
<configuration> 
    <input>
        <net-file value="D:\FTT\sumo_test\llcd\llcd.net.xml"/>
        <route-files value="D:\FTT\sumo_test\llcd\llcd.rou.xml"/>
        <additional-files value="D:\FTT\sumo_test\llcd\llcd.add.xml"/>
    </input>    
    <output>
        <lanechange-output value="D:\FTT\sumo_test\llcd\llcd.lanechange.xml"/>  
        <summary-output value="D:\FTT\sumo_test\llcd\output_sumo.xml"/>
    </output>       
    <time>
        <begin value="0"/>
        <end value="3600"/>
    </time>     
    <processing>
        <time-to-teleport value="-1"/>
    </processing>  
    <report>
        <no-duration-log value="true"/>
        <no-step-log value="true"/>
        <no-warnings value="true"/>
    </report>
</configuration>
```

If anyone can give some insights? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. I found veins_launchd will change the configure file of SUMO by adding

```
<random_number>
    <random value="false"/>
    <seed value="0"/>
</random_number>
```